# How do you find an selected item in a listboxfor multi-select dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multi-select dropdown list and I need to find out if a specific option is selected using jquery.

I have the following just to test if the event is firing but it isn't

```
        $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
            const ddl = $('#ddlUsers');
            alert(ddl.text());
        });
```

Comment: Try to use `F12` to see what's the error message in the console.

Comment: No errors are listed

Answer (score 0):

I moved the function to inside the $(document).ready function and it started working but I don't know why.

Comment: I don't put it inside the $(document).ready function and it works too.When you create a function inside $(document).ready, it's guaranteed that it won't be called before the document has loaded.